# Prevent Windows desktop application from interrupting sleep

Tags: .net, wpf, winapi, windows

I have a Windows desktop program (Tweetz) that interrupts/prevents sleep mode when running. The nature of the program is to monitor twitter and update the UI as tweets arrive. I suspect the network activity and/or updating the UI is preventing/interrupting sleep mode.

Is there a System API that can tell Windows that an application should not prevent sleeping?

Comment: You are looking at this the wrong way. Something is wrong with your program. Work out what it is and fix it. The function call you are looking for does not exist. Because it is not necessary.

Comment: *"Is there a System API that can tell Windows that an application should not prevent sleeping?"* - No, but the opposite is possible: [SetThreadExecutionState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208.aspx). Maybe the application uses this as a *"feature"*. UI updates will not prevent the system from entering sleep, but network traffic might (see [System Sleep Criteria](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373233.aspx)).

Comment: So it's likely the network traffic that's monitoring twitter that kills sleeping. Seems like a catch 22. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Don't guess. Isolate and identify the problem.

Comment: They are constructive. You are wasting your time by trying to guess what the issue is. You need to learn how to debug and identify your problem. Then you can take a well informed decision. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following approach. Code the Twitter monitor in a windows service and buffer any message that you need to display. For these messages, check if the system is in sleep mode or if the desktop is locked (according to your applications specifications). Set up some communication mechanism with your desktop application and transfer messages when needed/possible. The service won't prevent your system from going to sleep, you can monitor session state changes with SetServiceStatus() using SERVICE_ACCEPT_SESSIONCHANGE. You could also use the [OnSessionChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onsessionchange(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Windows successfully sleeps but your app immediately wakes it up by sending network traffic.  If so, you could handle `WM_POWERBROADCAST` messages, especially [PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372716(v=vs.85).aspx) and [PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372718(v=vs.85).aspx).  Stop network traffic on suspend, and restart it on Resume.

Comment: Set the sleep for one minute, wait for sleep, tweet comes in, system wakes up. I've also found that if I disconnect the network, the system remains asleep. Not a definitive test but it sure does point a finger at the network activity thing. I'll do as you suggest. At least it won't wake up then.